# Undefined symbol error for cURL installed at /usr/local/lib

Tags: curl, gcc, linker, libcurl

I a m trying to use libcurl on a Raspeberry Pi running Raspbian 9.4 Stretch. I follow the [instructions](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/GIT-INFO) to install the library by running buildcong, configure and make. The library is installed in /usr/local/lib.

The program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   CURL *curl;
   curl_mime *form = NULL;

   curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
   curl = curl_easy_init();

   if(curl) 
      form = curl_mime_init(curl);
}
```

It is compiled with:
`g++ test.cpp -o test -I/usr/local/lib/curl-master/include -L/usr/local/lib/curl-master/lib/.libs  -l:libcurl.so`

The error is at run-time:
`symbol lookup error: ./test: undefined symbol: curl_mime_init`

Replacing the end with `-lcurl` returns the same error.

Comment: Looks like a path problem. Are you sure about the `curl-master` component? Add `-Wl,-R,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags` to your `LDFLAGS`. If you want to run in-place using `.libs` directory, then you can override with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: I don't have much experience with make files. What do you mean those to LDFLAGS? Do I need to add them to the makefile? Run `configure`?  How do I override with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: I changed the folder name to curl_master

Comment: Typically you don't change `--prefix`; you take the default of `/usr/local`. However you still need to add `-Wl,-R,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags` to `LDFLAGS`. Or you can work around the Linux path problems that have existed for the last 20 years or so with band aides like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[curl_mime_init()](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_init.html) was introduced in libcurl 7.56.0. You're most likely linking with an older libcurl version.

Comment: The system is new; I am sure I didn't install previously. There is a curl executable in /usr/bin. `g++ test2.cpp -o test -I/usr/local/lib/curl_master/include -L/usr/local/lib/curl_master/lib/.libs  -l:libcurl.so` does build. The program with that build command builds and runs if the the call to `curl_mime_init()` is not included.

Comment: ...which would be a further indication that your libcurl is older than 7.56.0!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. curl is installed by default on the new system.